# find the area of the octagon

Tags: geometry, area

> Find the area of the colored octagon (tell the ratio between square $ABCD$ and the colored polygon).
>
> [image: the colored octagon]
>
> Square $ABCD$ is a perfect square, and $E,F,G,H$ are the midpoints of the line they are at.
>
> *(**Hint:** The top-left dot of the octagon is the center of gravity of triangle $ABD$.)*

This question is derived from IMTS R19 Question 5.

Comment: What have you tried already, and what techniques do you know of which might help you? We are not here to blindly answer questions which look like they may be homework questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: referring to the figure below and letting $BC=4$, can you show $NE=1$, $XN=1$ and calculate the area of triangle $XMN$?

$\hspace{5cm}$[image]

Can you generalize it for any square with $BC=a$? You should get a formula for the areas in terms of $a$.

Comment: Thanks I solved it. I got the answer.